# How can I create a loop to add spaces between elements of a string in python?

Tags: python, string

I am looking for a way to add spaces between words in a string until len(string) < n is reached.
I've tried this:

```
string = "you are great"
n = 20
res = []
for i in string:
    if ord(i) == 32 and len(string) < num:
        res = [string + i]
```

And I want it to add spaces between "you" and "are", and "are" and "great.
So it gives me something like this:

```
res = ["you     are    great"]
```

But instead I get this

```
"you are great "
```

Comment: How do you decide the two words between which you will add spaces? Why not add all the spaces between `you` and `are` and none between `are` and `great`?

Comment: Also why do you expect this code to work? 1. You always overwrite `res` in every iteration, so you will only get the result of the last iteration. 2. You _append_ a space to the end of _original string_, why do you expect spaces to go in between words? 3. Since you only ever operate with the original string, how would the spaces accumulate?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi my question is precisely the one you made on your 2nd point, how can I make the loop to print the spaces between the two words? I don't know how to do that, hence why I asked.

Comment: You can use the rstrip() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of loops:

```
string = "you are great"
n = 20
a = n - len(string.replace(' ', ''))    # amount of spaces to add
b = string.split()                      # list of words (without spaces)
if a & 1:
    b[0] += ' '                         # if 'a' is odd, add an extra space to first word
d = (' ' * (a // 2)).join(b)            # concatenate all words with 'a' spaces between them
print(d)
```

The output is:

```
"you     are    great"
```

Answer (score -1):

You code is doing what it is suppose to do but as you can see in the second output it adds a space to your string. The code below is the issue.

```
Res = [string + i]
```